# Facebook New Videos not showing on video table

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been working on Facebook API. I use fql for accessing users video.

My code goes like this

```
$fql = 'SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner= '.$uid;
$params = array(
                    'method' => 'fql.query',
                    'query' => $fql,
                    'access_token'=>$access_token
                    );
$videos = $facebook->api($params);
```

Its only showing old videos, but the new videos from last few days is not being showed in videos list.

Also I tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{vid}/?access_token=my_access_token
```

It only returns video for old videos, for new video it returns false.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Also, the number of returns are inconsistent. Has anyone have a solution for this? Or is this a limitation in Facebook? "Sacrificing accuracy for speed"?